# how to create image with a popup pane when user click?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on image(html tag), I would like show a popup panel (ex:like popup pane in facebook when we click on picture).
note: popup pane should contain image and text(retrieve from database).

How could I do that ?
thx you in advance

Comment: This question is too broad. Please post examples of your code and exactly where you are stuck

Comment: Well there is already ready to use jquery script such as lightbox, fancybox, shadowbox and what not. Use google and search `jQuery Content popup plugins` You'll find more then enough to find one that fits your needs

Comment: Having something pop up on a user click would involve client side scripting (ie JavaScript). To retrieve data from a database, look into ajax. Jquery is a JavaScript library that would help with both of these tasks, and simplify the Ajax.

Comment: sounds like he/she is looking for a jQuery lightbox [click here](http://fancybox.net/) to see if this is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of this:

In your HTML page, add this kind of code:

(first include [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) on your page of course)

> When I click on image(html tag),

```
$('#idOfWhateveriWant').on('click',function(){

});
```

> I would like show a popup panel (ex:like popup pane in facebook when we click on picture).

```
$('#idOfWhateveriWant').on('click',function(){
   //window.open("whatever") 
   //ABOVE NOT RECOMMENDED

   //use below instead

   $.ajax({
   url: 'ajax/test.php',
   success: function(data) {
      $('.result').html(data);
      //or use some jquery plugin you made 
      //or external plugin
      // to make your pane appear
      //$.WHateverPopupPanePlugin(whatever,data)
      alert('Load was performed.');
   }); //SEE http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
});
```

> note: popup pane should contain image and text(retrieve from
>   database).

IN ajax/test.php:

1. configure mysql database first,
2. put some data in it
3. Add some code like this to access stuff from your database and echo it as a JSON object

Php example below:

```
 <?php 

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "root";

  $databaseName = "ajax01";
  $tableName = "variables";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Additional help:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com
- http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107